# ValueError: X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 8, the number of features at training time

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to plot an SVM line with support vectors but I am getting the below error. Is there any possibility I can overcome it?

**Code**

```
def plot_svc_decision_function(model, ax=None, plot_support=True):
if ax is None:
    ax = plt.gca()
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

# create grid to evaluate model
x = np.linspace(xlim[0], xlim[1], 30)
y = np.linspace(ylim[0], ylim[1], 30)
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y, x)
xy = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
P = model.decision_function(xy).reshape(X.shape)

# plot decision boundary and margins
ax.contour(X, Y, P, colors='k',
           levels=[-1, 0, 1], alpha=0.5,
           linestyles=['--', '-', '--'])

# plot support vectors
if plot_support:
    ax.scatter(model.support_vectors_[:, 0],
               model.support_vectors_[:, 1],
               s=300, linewidth=1, facecolors='none');
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
plt.scatter(X_train.iloc[:, 0], X_train.iloc[:, 1], c=y_train, s=50, cmap='autumn')
plot_svc_decision_function(svm)
```

**Error**

*ValueError: X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 8, the number of features at training time*

Comment: Please provide more context, and the Traceback

Comment: Could you correct the function indentation and give the full traceback?